# How can i populate my array within a function then use the array outside the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

So I am populating an array within a function but when i call on that array outside of the function im pretty sure it comes out as a string. The array works fine inside the function when I try to call [1] but if I try to do that outside the function it comes up as undefined.

Hope someone can help me out as i am almost finished this code but this is stopping me, thanks.

Just for reference in case its helpful, when I console log outside the function it comes up like this:

```
[]
0: 7604
1: 7606
2: 7607
3: 7608
```

Then within the function like this:

```
(4) [7604, 7606, 7607, 7608]
0: 7604
1: 7606
2: 7607
3: 7608
```

Here is also the code, I have removed the token for security purposes also ignore some parts of the code like posturl as they will be used once I have figured this out:

```
var geturl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/suppressions/ibrarr2000@gmail.com";
var posturl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/groups/"+  +"/suppressions";
var deleteurl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/asm/groups/"+  +"/suppressions/ibrarr2000@gmail.com";
var token = "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";
let headers = new Headers();
let myData = {};
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
//supressionids = new Array();
var supressionids = [];

fetch(geturl, {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: headers,
}).then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    myData = data;
    buildSelect(data);
});

function buildSelect(d) {
    let select = document.createElement('form');
    d.suppressions.forEach(function (item) {
        let label = document.createElement('label');
        let option = document.createElement('input');
        option.value = item.suppressed;
        option.type = "checkbox";
        option.setAttribute("onclick","task(event);");
        option.id = item.id;
        option.classList = "subbox";
        option.textContent = item.name;
        label.textContent = item.name;
        select.appendChild(label);
        select.appendChild(option);

        supressionids.push(item.id);

        let br = document.createElement('br');
        select.appendChild(br);

        if(JSON.stringify(item.suppressed) == 'false'){
            option.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
    });
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(select);

    console.log(supressionids);

}

console.log(supressionids);

function task(e) {
  if(e.target.checked){
    fetch(deleteurl, {
         method: 'DELETE',
         headers: headers,
        });
  } else {
    fetch(posturl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ "recipient_emails": [ "ibrarr2000@gmail.com" ] }),
      headers: headers,
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to get the array values before the `GET request` is done.

Comment: @eag845 Thats how this api works mate, 100% sure that not the issue the GET request works fine, and as mentioned the post and delete will be used later on, all i want to do is populate the array supressionids and then continue to use that array outside the function but it seems impossible

Comment: eag845 is not saying the GET isn't working. He's saying the code hits that `console.log` outside the function before the data has been returned - the code doesn't wait to run it. What you want to do is use a function to contain all the code to be run in your final `.then()` that replaces `buildSelect`. Inside that function, call `buildSelect` and run the rest of your code.

Comment: @eag845 I will try this out, could you do the code and show me exactly how i should be running the code, i have also added a token so you can test it for yourself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `GET` takes some time to get the data. While the data is being retrieved, the code moves on to the next piece, which is the `console.log` in the same scope. Use a function to contain all the code you want to run. Change your `fetch` to this:

```
fetch(geturl, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
}).then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    myData = data;
    runCode(data);
});
```

Then add a containing function:

```
function runCode(data){
    buildSelect(data);
    console.log(supressionids);
}
```

Your other option is to contain all the code inside the `.then()` call or use multiple `.then()` calls.

Comment: This worked exactly as I wished, thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, it almost does sorry, when I put the taske function in the run code function it says task is undefined, and I can't seem to call that function if i put it out the runcode? How would i call this?